# React native None of these files exist: error?

Tags: javascript, react-native

the path of the file is correct but I get the following error

```
None of these files exist:
  * src\pages\Test(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * src\pages\Test\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
   7 |
   8 | import React from 'react';
>  9 | import Test from './src/pages/Test';
     |                   ^
  10 |
  11 | function App() {
  12 |   return (]
```

FOLDER STRUCTURE;
[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sddca.png)

created new project.

```js
import react from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
    
export default function Test() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not sure what is happening. Could you add your `Test` file as well?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a space somewhere after your `page ` folder name or before your `src` folder name?

Comment: added @devpolo, no space

Comment: Have you tried: `npm start --clean-cache` or this: `expo start -c`?

Comment: Looks like your slashes are going in different directions. If you're on a Windows system, use \. Otherwise use `/`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your Text component fix import

```
import react from 'react';
```

TO

```
import React from 'react';
```